# how to set up a bitrise trigger to upload files to google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bitrise

I'm trying to add a new app on bitrise for our HTML based website.
I have tried to add a new app on bitrise, but I couldn't figure out how to set the new app as a static website on google storage.
is there a way to set up a trigger on bitrise to upload files and directories to google cloud storage bucket when pushing code to bitbucket repository?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that from a Script, using e.g. Google Cloud CLI which is preinstalled on the Linux stacks https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects includes example for `gsutil` for example.

Authentication with a Service Account: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account
Note: you can use the Bitrise Generic File Storage to store the service account json key file: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-generic-file-storage/#uploading-files-to-generic-file-storage-on-bitriseio

A base workflow would look like this:

1. SSH Auth and Git Clone steps, to download the code
2. `File Downloader` step to download the Service Account JSON file (the one you upload into the Generic File Storage: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-generic-file-storage/#uploading-files-to-generic-file-storage-on-bitriseio ). Alternatively if you'd want to store it in encrypted form you can use the `Decrypt file` step as mentioned in the guide ( https://devcenter.bitrise.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-generic-file-storage/#using-the-files-uploaded-to-generic-file-storage-on-bitriseio )
3. And then a `Script` step, where you activate/auth the service account file ( https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account ), and then you use `gcloud` / `gsutil` any way you like.